# Can't Remove Workbook in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Editing as suggested answer didn't work

The suggested methods all seem to be ways to remove hidden or locked  sheets.
not "rogue workbooks" like in my screenshots

I have a spreadsheet, with quite a bit of vba code in it and various sheets.

Today an additional workbook (as well as the This Workbook) has appeared in my object explorer.

And it's taken the name of one of my other sheets. I've no idea what caused it to be created.

In the screenshot Sales Record was labeled SalesRecordSheet  and referenced in all my code that way.
I don't know how this new workbook got created and it took the name SalesRecordSheet (causing my original sheet to be renamed SalesRecordSheet1)

I can't get rid of it though. I could go through all my code and change the label to match SalesRecordSheet1

It's just pretty annoying.

Has anyone encountered this before? And know how to get rid of it? (and potentially tell me how I created it in the first place, so I can avoid in future)

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove a non-existant Sheet in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24497772/remove-a-non-existant-sheet-in-vba)

Comment: @niton Thanks for that. I'll take a look.

Comment: unfortunately none of the solutions in that post worked

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26278046/vba-code-deletes-its-own-sheet-leaving-a-ghost-sheet-behind

Comment: If still unsuccessful [edit] the question. Add the links and indicate the attempts and results if any. I am following. I will vote to reopen.

Comment: I edited the question, but it still says it's associated with an answer.

Basically the suggestions in that link seem to be on how to remove hidden sheets.

I could potentially recreate the whole spreadsheet, however am reluctant as it's made up of alot of code and sheets as well as close to a hundred named ranges

Comment: "The suggested methods all seem to be ways to remove hidden or locked sheets. not "rogue workbooks" like in my screenshots". What does this mean? One answer was "copy all of the "real" worksheets to a new workbook". https://stackoverflow.com/a/24498149/1571407

Comment: @MichaelLiew just because you edit your question doesn't mean it will be opened. The question is still not very good, contains no code, doesn't show what you did and mentions things like `rogue workbooks` that simply don't exist. Editing makes the question *eligible* for reopening. People have to vote to reopen it. I don't see any improvement in the question. The only thing added was `it didn't work`